# What's the simplest test that I can do to check if my cron jobs are working?

Tags: cron

What's the simplest test that I can do to check if my cron jobs are working?

Comment: Do you want a simple or reliable check?

Comment: Simple check will do, like Andy's answer. A more complicated check might also prove useful in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a test cron:

> */5 * * * *  echo "test" >
>   /tmp/crontest.txt

This will write "test" to the file /tmp/crontest.txt every 5 minutes

Ensure the cron daemon `crond` is running using

> [andy@server]# ps aux | grep cron
>
> root      4321  0.0  0.0  76543  3211
>   ?        Ss   Jul31   0:07 crond

Check the logs using

> tail /var/log/cron

Try `date` to ensure you are in the correct timezone

Comment: I had to make the first parameter to 0-59/5 to make it work.

Comment: Apologies it should have read */5, have amended answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply change their execution time and see the result ! :)

If you have cron that will run on

> 12 24 * * *

change it to

> mm hh * * *

where hh and mm is an hour and minute very near to the actual time.

Once verified the execution restore the correct timing

Comment: +1 for tip on changing the execution time

Answer (score -2):

/2**** touch cronrunning >/root/Desktop

it will show u file coming to desktop

Comment: Downvoted: Bad practice, invalid syntax, bad spelling.